# How to delete all shapes Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a code that get from a sql database the locations relatated to a selected text. For which text I have a button (`btn_locations`) with attributes by type (marker, polygon, circle, rectangle and polyline) that contains the data to set the related shapes at the map.

Until this moment of showing the shapes at the map, when you click each button, is going fine. What I didn't get is how to set the map null, deleting all shapes.

What I have in mind is to get the shapes shown at map by type and set null for each one (markers, polygons, circles, rectangles and polylines), but I didn't find out how to do it.

```
var btn_map = document.getElementsByClassName('btn_locations');

for (var i=0; i < btn_mapa.length; i++) {
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(btn_map[i], 'click', function() {

    var marker_data = this.getAttribute('data-marker');
    var polyline_data = this.getAttribute('data-polyline');
    var rectangle_data = this.getAttribute('data-rectangle');
    var circle_data = this.getAttribute('data-circle');
    var polygon_data = this.getAttribute('data-polygon');

    if (marker_data != '') {
      var markers = (new Function("return [" + marker_data + "];")());
      for (var k = 0; k < markers.length; k++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[k].lat, markers[k].lng);
        markers[k] = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: marker,
          map: map,
          }
        });
      }   
    } 

    if (polyline_data != '') { 
      var polylines = (new Function("return [" + polyline_data + "];")());
      for (var k = 0; k < polylines.length; k++) {
        var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: polylines[k],
          geodesic: true,
          strokeColor: '#fbb03b',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 5
        });
        polyline.setMap(map);
      }
    }

    if (rectangle_data != '') {
      var rectanglesBounds = (new Function("return [" + rectangle_data + "];")());
      for (var k = 0; k < rectanglesBounds.length; k++) {           
        var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
          strokeColor: '#fbb03b',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 1,
          fillColor: '#fbb03b',
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          bounds: rectanglesBounds[k]
        });
          rectangle.setMap(map);
      }
    }

    if (circle_data != '') {
      var circles = (new Function("return [" + circle_data + "];")());
      for (var k = 0; k < circles.length; k++) {
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          strokeColor: '#fbb03b',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 1,
          fillColor: '#fbb03b',
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          center: circles[k].center,
          radius: circles[k].radius
        });
          circle.setMap(map);
      }
    }

    if (polygon_data != '') {
      var polygons = (new Function("return [" + polygon_data + "];")());
      for (var k = 0; k < polygons.length; k++) {
        var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: polygons[k], 
          strokeColor: "#fbb03b",
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 1,
          fillColor: '#fbb03b',
          fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
        polygon.setMap(map);
      }
    } 

  });
}

var btn_clear_all= document.getElementsById('btn_clear');

google.maps.event.addDomListener(btn_clear_all, 'click', function() {
//delete all shapes shown at map
});
```

Comment: `setMap(null)` instead of `setMap(map)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it by adding a x.push(type) in each type

```
        if (circle_data != '') {
          var circles = (new Function("return [" + circle_data + "];")());
          for (var k = 0; k < circles.length; k++) {
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
              map: map,
              strokeColor: '#fbb03b',
              strokeOpacity: 0.8,
              strokeWeight: 1,
              fillColor: '#fbb03b',
              fillOpacity: 0.35,
              center: circles[k].center,
              radius: circles[k].radius
            });
            gcircles.push(circle);
          }
        }
```

and then setting the map null for them:

```
var gmarkers = [];
var gpolylines = [];
var grectangles = [];
var gcircles = [];
var gpolygons = [];

var btn_clear_all = document.getElementsByClassName('btn_clear');
for (var i=0; i < btn_clear_all .length; i++) {
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(btn_clear_all[i], 'click', function() {            

        for (k = 0; k < gmarkers.length; k++) {
            gmarkers[k].setMap(null);
        }
        for (k = 0; k < gpolylines.length; k++) {
            gpolylines[k].setMap(null);
        }
        for (k = 0; k < grectangles.length; k++) {
            grectangles[k].setMap(null);
        }
        for (k = 0; k < gcircles.length; k++) {
            gcircles[k].setMap(null);
        }
        for (k = 0; k < gpolygons.length; k++) {
            gpolygons[k].setMap(null);
        }
    });
}
```